# How to enable the Downloads Popup in Vivaldi

Tags: vivaldi

The current major version of Vivaldi (v5.x) supposedly contains a Downloads Popup to help organizing the downloads.

According to their [help](https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/panels/downloads/), it can be set like this:

> 1. Go to Settings > Downloads.
> 2. Enable Display Downloads in a Popup.

I checked my settings, it contains ***only 4 options*** and none of them is relevant:

[image]

I did try resetting the defaults.

I use this version: **5.3.2679.55** (Stable channel) (64-bit)

Where could I set it to use the Downloads Popup?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see the *Display Downloads in a Popup* option either, [from their documentation](https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/panels/downloads/#Downloads_Popup).  Regardless, try this: right-click on the main toolbar (containing the address bar and extensions button), select **Edit > Customize Toolbar**, drag-and-drop the **Downloads** button from the Toolbar Editor to the main toolbar (eg, next to Extensions button).  Click **Done** to close the Toolbar Editor.

Comment: Seems like a bug. There's a "Open Downloads Popup" keyboard command that has no keyboard combination assigned to it by default. When I assigned one, invoking it didn't do anything. I'd suggest filing a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

From the Left side of the bar on the panel icon right-click then:

> 1. Edit > Customize Toolbar
> 2. Drag-and-drop the Downloads button from the Toolbar Editor to the main toolbar.

Credit to [leeharvey1](https://superuser.com/users/1535708/leeharvey1) from the comments.